# hibernate - why mocked method throws NullPointerException

Tags: spring, hibernate, mocking, mockito, integration-testing

I'm trying to prepare some easy parking service api and i'm stuck at testing.

i have ParkingService like:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ParkingService {
      private final CarsAndParkingsRepository carsAndParkingsRepository;
      private final ParkingsRepository parkingsRepository;
```

and simple custom method in repositories

```
public boolean checkFreeSlots(String idParking) {
    return carsAndParkingsRepository.findAmountOfTakenSlotsOnParking(idParking)
            < parkingsRepository.findByIdParking(idParking).getNumberOfParkingSlots();
}
```

and test:

```
 @Test
public void checkFreeSlotsIfIsCorrect() {
    //given

    //when
    when(carsAndParkingsRepository.findAmountOfTakenSlotsOnParking("5")).thenReturn(5);
    when(parkingsRepository.findByIdParking("5").getNumberOfParkingSlots()).thenReturn(10);
    when(parkingService.checkFreeSlots("5")).thenCallRealMethod();
    boolean result = parkingService.checkFreeSlots("5");

    //then
    assertEquals(true, result);
}
```

but the problem is i'm getting NullPointerException at line:

```
when(parkingsRepository.findByIdParking("5").getNumberOfParkingSlots()).thenReturn(10);
```

Previous mocked method when(carsAndParkingsRepository.findAmountOfTakenSlotsOnParking("5")).thenReturn(5) works correctly, its return 5 but in next line other repository throws exception.
Is there any other way to test it or i'm doing something wrong? Ofc, i have mocked repositories :)

Comment: When stubbing, the methods are called as usual. `when(parkingsRepository.findByIdParking("5").getNumberOfParkingSlots())`
As you haven't stubbed findByIdParking, it returns null, hence a NPE.

Comment: how can i stub findByIdParking? I didnt hear about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in line:

```java
when(parkingsRepository.findByIdParking("5").getNumberOfParkingSlots()).thenReturn(10);
```

The argument to `when` needs to get evaluated before the call:

- `parkingsRepository.findByIdParking("5")` is called and return `null`
- `null.getNumberOfParkingSlots()` is called and throws NPE

You have following options:

**Use a POJO for the Parking**

```java
var parking5 = new Parking(
    5, //id
   10, //number of slots
   // ... other arguments
);
when(parkingsRepository.findByIdParking("5")).thenReturn(parking5);
```

This is the preferred option, but if your object is difficult to construct (it should not be the case for hibernate entity), you can use a mock

**Use an mock of the Parking**

```java
var parking5 = mock(Parking.class);
when(parkingsRepository.findByIdParking("5")).thenReturn(parking5);
when(parking5.getNumberOfParkingSlots()).thenReturn(10);
```

Note that you can use chained calls in this approach, but this requires that you stub the methods in order.

```java
var parking5 = mock(Parking.class);
when(parkingsRepository.findByIdParking("5")).thenReturn(parking5);
when(parkingsRepository.findByIdParking("5").getNumberOfParkingSlots()).thenReturn(10);
```

In my opinion, first flavour is easier to use, and lets you to reorder stubbings.

Comment: Thank you man, i spent half of the night and did almost the same solution with mock and it works correctly. Thanks for explanation step by step :)